# Showing nested excel data into one single data in json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, excel

I used `react-excel-renderer` to get data from an excel file. The excel file has data like the following image:

[image: excel data]

In the frontend, I got `json data` like this:

[image: json data]

How do I make group them as one based on the `accId`? I plan to have a table to render their `id` and `name` and there will button to view the rest of the data.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Table, Button, message, Upload } from "antd";
import { ExcelRenderer } from "react-excel-renderer";

export const ExcelPageMod = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);
  const [cols, setCols] = useState([]);
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);

  const { Column } = Table;

  const fileHandler = (fileList) => {
    let fileObj = fileList;

    if (!fileObj) {
      message.error("No file uploaded!");
      return false;
    }
    console.log("fileObj.type:", fileObj.type);

    if (
      !(
        fileObj.type === "application/vnd.ms-excel" ||
        fileObj.type ===
          "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
      )
    ) {
      message.error("Unknown file format. Only Excel files are uploaded!");
    }

    ExcelRenderer(fileObj, (err, resp) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        let newRows = [];
        resp.rows.slice(1).map((row, index) => {
          if (row && row !== "undefined") {
            newRows.push({
              key: index,
              accId: row[0],
              accName: row[1],
              productClass: row[2],
              accYearPrev: row[3],
              accYearCurr: row[4],
            });
          }
        });

        if (newRows.length === 0) {
          message.error("No data found in file!");
          return false;
        } else {
          console.log(newRows);
          console.log(resp)
          setCols(resp.cols);
          setRows(newRows);
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  };

  const handleDownload = (key) => {
    const selectedRow = [...rows];

    console.log(selectedRow[key]);
    setSelected(selectedRow[key]);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
      <h1>Production PDF Generator</h1>
      <div>
        <Upload
          name="file"
          multiple={false}
          beforeUpload={fileHandler}
          onRemove={() => setRows([])}
        >
          <Button type="primary">Upload</Button>
        </Upload>
      </div>
      <div style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
        <Table dataSource={rows}>
          <Column title="ID" dataIndex="accId" key="accId" />
          <Column title="Name" dataIndex="accName" key="accName" />
          <Column title="Product Class" dataIndex="productClass" key="productClass" />
          <Column
            title="Year Prev"
            dataIndex="accYearPrev"
            key="accYearPrev"
            render={(accYearPrev) => {
              return (
                <>{"Rp. " + parseFloat(accYearPrev).toLocaleString("id")}</>
              );
            }}
          />
          <Column
            title="Year Curr"
            dataIndex="accYearCurr"
            key="accYearCurr"
            render={(accYearCurr) => {
              return (
                <>{"Rp. " + parseFloat(accYearCurr).toLocaleString("id")}</>
              );
            }}
          />
          <Column
            title="Action"
            key="action"
            render={(text, record) => (
              <Button type="primary" onClick={() => handleDownload(record.key)}>
                Get Data
              </Button>
            )}
          />
        </Table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Edit: Here's is the JSON I want

```
    {
      "accId": "ABC001",
      "accName": "John Doe",
      "production": [
        { "productClass": "General", "accYearPrev": 2000, "accYearCurr": 2500 },
        {
          "productClass": "Engineering",
          "accYearPrev": 7000,
          "accYearCurr": 5500
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "accId": "ABC002",
      "accName": "Jane Doe",
      "production": [
        { "productClass": "General", "accYearPrev": 2000, "accYearCurr": 2500 },
        {
          "productClass": "Engineering",
          "accYearPrev": 7000,
          "accYearCurr": 5500
        },
        { "productClass": "Marine", "accYearPrev": 7000, "accYearCurr": 5500 }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: see: [How to group an array of objects by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-to-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key)

Comment: @pilchard thanks for the reference, but its little bit hard for me to render it as a table. I am using antd table for my case. It would be ideal if the json can be like my edited post. Or is there any other pointers or suggestions that I could take into consideration?

Comment: It's the same, but you need to return only the `Object.values()` of the result and slightly refactor the grouped objects. If you include a sample of your input array I can make an example for you.

Comment: @pilchard That would be wonderful. This is the input [data](https://pastebin.com/T2fJbhJy). Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really just a [group-by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-to-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key) but instead of returning the accumulator object you can return the [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) of the accumulator. Properties that will be used to construct the new object in the accumulator, or are not needed, are [destructured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in the callback parameters.

```js
const input = [ { accId: 'ABC0001', accName: 'JOHN DOE', accYearCurr: 1250000, accYearPrev: 1000000, key: 0, productClass: 'General', }, { accId: 'ABC0001', accName: undefined, accYearCurr: 1750000, accYearPrev: 1500000, key: 1, productClass: 'Marine Cargo', }, { accId: 'ABC0001', accName: undefined, accYearCurr: 1000000, accYearPrev: 1125000, key: 2, productClass: 'Motor', }, { accId: 'ABC0001', accName: undefined, accYearCurr: 7500000, accYearPrev: 5500000, key: 3, productClass: 'Property', }, { accId: 'ABC0002', accName: 'JANE DOE', accYearCurr: 5000000, accYearPrev: 7500000, key: 4, productClass: 'Engineering', }, { accId: 'ABC0002', accName: undefined, accYearCurr: 10000000, accYearPrev: 10000000, key: 5, productClass: 'Property', }, { accId: 'ABC0003', accName: 'JILL DOE', accYearCurr: 75000000, accYearPrev: 70500000, key: 6, productClass: 'Marine Cargo', }, { accId: 'ABC0003', accName: undefined, accYearCurr: 10000000, accYearPrev: 10000000, key: 7, productClass: 'Motor', }, { accId: 'ABC0003', accName: undefined, accYearCurr: 35000000, accYearPrev: 25000000, key: 8, productClass: 'Engineering', }, ];

const result = Object.values(
  input.reduce((a, { accId, accName, key, ...prod }) => {
    (a[accId] ??= { accId, accName, production: [] }).production.push(prod);

    return a;
  }, {})
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

The above snippet uses the [logical nullish assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) operator, but if you can't use it for compatiblity reasons it can be replaced with an OR(||) short-circuit.

```
(a[accId] || (a[accId] = { accId, accName, production: [] })).production.push(_production);
```

It's unclear if you want the `accYearCurr/Prev` values changed, but you can handle any changes needed before pushing to the accumulator.

```
const result = Object.values(
  input.reduce((a, { accId, accName, key, ..._production }) => {
    _production.accYearCurr /= 1000;
    _production.accYearPrev /= 1000;

    (a[accId] ??= { accId, accName, production: [] }).production.push(_production);

    return a;
  }, {})
);
```